# What is the use of this component packaged with a strain gauge?

Tags: strain-gage

I ordered the strain gauge with code 865-6235 from [rscomponents](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/strain-gauges/8656235/).

I don't understand the use of the other highlighted part. Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: From the product website and datasheet:

*• Supplied with two self-adhesive terminal pads*

So that's *what* it is, not what it's for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a "bondable terminal" whose use is demonstrated in this video:

Tutorial: How to Install a Strain Gage for Maximum Fatigue Life and High Elongation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fj4XzjP6Ac

Comment: sorry but I watched the video and still don't understand what is its use / why it is needed. Could you explain a little further?

Comment: Your cable wires attach to the provided pads and then you use whisker wires to attach the pads to the strain gauge.

Comment: You are describing how to use it and not why you use it. Anyway I'll accept the answer and try to look for more informations elsewhere

Comment: One good reason is that it makes it easier to attach a different cable to the gauge. The wires coming from the gauge look very fragile. This way you don't have to try to solder your cable wires directly to the gauge wires. It also provides more rigidity and a strain relief -- if you tug on your cable you won't be pulling directly on the gauge wires. You'll still want to make sure there's a strain relief on your cable so that it doesn't pull too hard on the pads.

Answer (score 0):

> sorry but I watched the video and still don't understand what is its use / why it is needed

How will you use that strain gage? Presumably you want to electrically connect it to something. How would you go about doing it? The thin "whiskers" are bonded to directly to the metallization on the substrate of the gage. You don't want anything pulling on them.

The whisker wires must be securely attached to a terminal. You can't just solder them to a cable and put heatshrink on them. It's not practical, and it will rip the wires first chance.

So, the bondable terminal is there to provide strain relief, soldering terminals, and a fail-safe in case the cable was pulled on: the wires may rip from the terminal, but the strain gage and its fragile wiring should be intact.

Also, to be practical, the single "quarter-bridge" strain gage has to be connected with more than two wires to the instrumentation. Best performance comes with four wires: two force, two sense. The force and sense wire is combined on the bonding terminal, and connects to the strain gage "whisker wires".

Or, the strain gage will be combined with other strain gages to form a multi-gage transducer. The connections between those multiple gages need some terminals, and the bondable terminals are just right for the job.

Without the bondable terminals, there's hardly a way to actually use that strain gage without high likelihood of destroying it. I'm speaking from experience here :)

Also, make sure to get all the support chemicals and tools needed to install strain gages. The material to bond to should be flat and matted - ideally by sandblasting with a very fine medium. It must be degreased. It must be dust free - ideally, the installation should be done in a dedicated clean space. It doesn't need to be a clean room, but a room away from workshop dust and so on.

Right glue should be chosen - usually there's more than one choice, and it also depends on how durable you want the transducer to be. Read application guide from the vendor to get some direction.

Strain gages may be used temporarily on engineered structures to record/monitor their loading for a set time. Or they may be permanently installed in durable goods like in weigh scales or pressure transducers. The installation techniques used in each of those applications will differ somewhat - surface prep, glue choice, protective coating may all be different.

After the glue cures, the gage should be coated with a conformal coat to protect it from corrosion and contamination. If you don't have lots of gages to experiment with and qualify the process with, best go with the supplies and procedures suggested by the strain gage manufacturer.